# Wand + ImageMagick + Anaconda: "'wand' has no attribute 'image'"

Tags: python, windows, imagemagick, anaconda, wand

I'm having issues using these three together. I believe wand is not recognizing the ImageMagick libraries but I'm not sure.

Environment:
Python 3.5.1 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)
Windows 7

Set up instructions I took:

1. Installed ImageMagick-6.9.4-Q8 (x64) with the "C/C++ development
   headers options checked. (Installed to C:\Program
   Files\ImageMagick-6.9.4-Q8)
2. Set MAGICK_HOME envar C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.4-Q8
3. Installed wand from pip

My code:

```
import wand
...
with wand.image.Image(filename=source_file, resolution=(RESOLUTION, RESOLUTION)) as img:
...
```

Traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\pdf_convert.py", line 31, in <module>
    ret = pdf2jpg(f, target_file, 2480)
  File ".\pdf_convert.py", line 10, in pdf2jpg
    with wand.image.Image(filename=source_file, resolution=(RESOLUTION, RESOLUTION)) as img:
AttributeError: module 'wand' has no attribute 'image'
```

From everything I've seen I've followed the right setup instructions. I am using the 64 bit version of ImageMagick with the 64 bit version of Anaconda. This was working with me before until I started using Anaconda (before I was using regular 32 bit Python and 32 bit ImageMagick.)

Is there something I'm missing? Why is wand not working correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```py
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename=source_file, resolution=(RESOLUTION, RESOLUTION)) as img:
    pass
```

> Is there something I'm missing? Why is wand not working correctly?

I believe it is working as expected, and the original architect did not intend to allow top-package-level shortcuts (i.e. `import wand`). This kinda makes sense as [wand](/questions/tagged/wand) integrates to IM with [ctypes](/questions/tagged/ctypes), and does not attempt to resolve libraries during `setup.py`.

You can modify the package to include the module shortcuts your expecting by adding the following.

```py
# wand/__init__.py
import api
import color
import compat
import display
import drawing
import exceptions
import font
import image
import resource
import sequence
import version
```

But I wouldn't recommend this. The `from package.module import Class` is a lot more cleaner.

Comment: Yep that's it. Thank you! I don't know why it was working when I was misusing it before.

Comment: Perhaps you used `import wand.image` elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PIL.Image as well then use:

`from wand.image import Image as wand_image_Image`
`import PIL`